# hadoop - localhost is different than destination localhost

Tags: hadoop, localhost

I'm new to hadoop and I'm trying to config hadoop on my personal computer in "Pseudo-Distributed Operation" mod. I got this error when trying to run my mapreduce code:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: 
Failed on local exception: com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException: 
Protocol message tag had invalid wire type.; 
Host Details : local host is: "moshe-X541UV/127.0.1.1"; 
destination host is: "localhost":9000;
```

when I'm trying to run telnet on localhost 9000 I get this:

```
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
```

my **etc/hosts** file is:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       moshe-X541UV
.
.
.
```

and also my **core-site.xml** is:

```
<configuration>

<property>
    <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
    <value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

what I'm doing wrong?

EDIT:

**jpm** result:

```
18426 Jps
13036 SparkSubmit
```

I have Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS.
hadoop version is 2.7.3.

I'm try to use [this](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.8.0/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/MapReduceTutorial.html) tutorial

Comment: Did you built Hadoop with Maven by yourself? And it might be helpful if you tell the information like your Operating system, Hadoop version.

Also please execute 'jps' java command in your machine to know what all Hadoop services have been started.

Comment: I build the Hadoop on my own. the hadoop version is 2.7.3 and my system is Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS.
jps:18426 Jps
13036 SparkSubmit
@DineshKumarP

Comment: Please check whether the Protobuf version is 2.5.0. Because as per this ticket HADOOP-13363 - Version 2.5.0 is mandatory for Hadoop 2.7.3 and earlier.